# LibreOffice presentation: wider text background, like html padding?

Tags: libreoffice, text-editing

When setting a text's background in a LibreOffice presentation, it may look like this:

[image: libreoffice presentation text with colored background]

Is there a way to **increase the background size**, as in making it wider? I'm trying to get an effect similar to padding in HTML. A larger colored background area surrounding the text. I mean like this:

[image: wider background to create colored border around text] <sup>(this is photoshopped, not actual LibreOffice footage)</sup>

I tried changing the text's indentation, or its entire surrounding object rectangle, but that doesn't do it. The text background always seems to be restricted to the actual characters only.

Is there a way to pull this off in LibreOffice?

Answer (score 0):

#### Is there a way to increase the background size, as in making it wider?

Place the text in a text box:

1. "Insert" > "Text Box"
2. Add text
3. "Format" > "Alignment" > "Centered" and "Center"

   [image]
4. Right click "Area...", select "Area" tab, select "Fill" colour

   [image]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In LibreOffice Impress, right-click on the text frame and go to `Text...`.  Under `Spacing to Borders`, increase Left, Top, Right and Bottom.  Then press OK.

[image]

Comment: Tried this, but doesn't seem to work. I can expand the border spacing all I want, and I do indeed see the outer rectangle of the text object spaced around the text. But the text's background color remains applied *only* on the text itself, not the space around it. Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/5gHJFZI.png

Comment: Btw I also tried increasing the Spacing in the text's Paragraph settings, but also to no avail: http://i.imgur.com/RmXizIu.png